# How to have Default value in Byte format (string type) in REST definition Swagger file

Tags: swagger

help needed in a REST swagger file.

How can I have default value in a Byte format parameter. or is it even possible ? Tried this one, it doesn't work.

```
default: "MA=="
```

gives me this error, at compile time:

> incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to byte[]

example Swagger below:

```
someDVO:
    type: object
    description: Contains DocumentID Information.
    properties:
      specificDocID : 
        type: string
        format: byte
        description: The SiteSpecific ID representing the Document.
```

Any pointer, Thanks